# Pinescript v5 getting "no data" error on strategy

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I coded a very simple strategy on V5 to understand the code, that is getting a "No Data" message. Can someone help me out?

The script is:

```
//@version = 5
strategy("High/Low of Previous Candle Strategy",overlay = true,slippage = 10,initial_capital = 1000000,calc_on_every_tick = true,process_orders_on_close = false,default_qty_value = 10)
// Buy signal
buy_signal = high > high[1]
sell_signal = low<low[1]
// Set stop loss and take profit levels
stop_loss_buy = low[1]
stop_loss_sell = high[1]
take_profit_buy = high[1] + 1000 * syminfo.mintick
take_profit_sell = low[1] + 1000 * syminfo.mintick

// Enter trade on buy signal
if buy_signal
    strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long)
if strategy.position_size>0
    strategy.exit("Stop Loss/Take Profit", "Buy", stop = stop_loss_buy, limit = take_profit_buy)
if sell_signal
    strategy.entry("Sell",strategy.short)
if strategy.position_size<0
    strategy.exit("Stop Loss/Take Profit", "Sell", stop = stop_loss_sell, limit = take_profit_sell)
```

Answer (score 0):

See the alert message:
[image: alert message]

This error occurs when our strategy sends more than 3000 orders in backtest.
Your strategy opens positions on each candle, generating many orders

You can limit them by time
Something like that:

```
i_timeFrom = timestamp("2023-03-10")//yesterday
timeFrom = time(timeframe.period) > i_timeFrom
// Enter trade on buy signal
if buy_signal and timeFrom
    strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long)
```